# React/NextJS: How can I map an array of objects whose keys change?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, next.js

I'm working on a project in NextJS and I found an interesting problem for which I can't seem to find a solution -

I have an array of objects I've acquired from the Civic GAPI.  In this array, most the objects are general election contests, but some are also referendums.  The `contest` and `referendum` objects have different structures.

Here's a general election `contest` object:

```
14:
candidates: (2) [{…}, {…}]
district: {name: "Thurston County", scope: "countywide", id: "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa/county:thurston"}
level: ["administrativeArea2"]
office: "Commissioner District 3"
roles: ["legislatorUpperBody"]
sources: [{…}]
type: "General"
__proto__: Object
```

And here's a `referendum` object:

```
15:
district: {name: "Washington", scope: "statewide", id: "ocd-division/country:us/state:wa"}
referendumTitle: "Advisory Vote No. 8 (Senate Bill 6505)"
referendumUrl: "https://wei.sos.wa.gov/agency/osos/en/press_and_research/PreviousElections/2014/General-Election/Pages/Online-Voters-Guide.aspx"
sources: [{…}]
type: "Referendum"
__proto__: Object
```

Here's my page that renders this data (I've included the entire page, but obviously you can skip the conditionals for loading the data from GAPI):

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const Contests = (props) => {
  const url = '/api/voterInfo';
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

  if (error)
    return (
      <div className='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
        <span className='sr-only'>Failed to load data!</span>
      </div>
    );

  if (!data)
    return (
      <div
        className='spinner-border spinner-border-lg text-danger'
        role='status'
        style={{ margin: '10rem', width: '20rem', height: '20rem' }}
      ></div>
    );

  if (data && data !== null) {
    const { contests } = data.data;

    return (
      <div>
        <table className='table table-hover'>
          <caption>List of contests in your area</caption>
          <thead style={{ fontFamily: 'Righteous, sans-serif' }}>
            <tr>
              <th scope='col'>#</th>
              <th scope='col'>Dist ID</th>
              <th scope='col'>Dist Name</th>
              <th scope='col'>Dist Scope</th>
              <th scope='col'>Office</th>
              <th scope='col'>Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {contests.map((contest, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx}>
                <th scope={idx}>{idx + 1}</th>

                <td>{contest.district.id}</td>
                <td>{contest.district.name}</td>
                <td>{contest.district.scope}</td>
                <td>{contest.office}</td>
                <td>{contest.type}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {console.log(contests[0].level[0])}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Contests;
```

If I only render the first level of key-value pairs, it's easy to see how the difference in `contest` and `referendum` objects causes one or the other to miss values:

[image: Missing values from referendumTitle, referendumUrl]

Because I've set the map to render the keys from `contests` it misses the `referendum` values for keys `referendumTitle` and `referendumUrl`.

What's the best way to go about dealing with this?  I came up with two possible solutions I'm not sure how to implement:

Is there a conditional I could set to only map contests, and have a separate page to map referendums?  How would I separate them (before/while/after) mapping an array?

OR

Is there a way to dynamically map the values of the keys regardless of their identifier?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to dynamically map the values of the keys regardless of their identifier?

You could use Object.keys:

```
Object.keys(contest).map(key => console.log(key))
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea. How would you propose using the key values once they're obtained?

If I wanted to split the contests and referendums, how might I go about setting a condition for map? Any ideas?

Comment: To set a condition for map, use filter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the API's returned data into 3 categories with `if` statements, and then making a component to load each one separately, because they benefited from being formatted differently

But here's the initial page I created to debug the returned data. It separates the data but displays it all on one page, with conditional rendering based on what objects were returned:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import useSWR from 'swr';

const Contests = (props) => {
  const url = '/api/voterInfo';
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

  if (error)
    return (
      <div className='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
        <span className='sr-only'>Failed to load data!</span>
      </div>
    );

  if (!data)
    return (
      <div
        className='spinner-border spinner-border-lg text-danger'
        role='status'
        style={{ margin: '10rem', width: '20rem', height: '20rem' }}
      ></div>
    );

  if (data && data !== null) {
    const { contests } = data.data;

    const primaryElections = [];
    const generalElections = [];
    const referendums = [];
    contests.map((contest) => {
      if (contest.type === 'Referendum') {
        referendums.push(contest);
      } else if (contest.type === 'General') {
        generalElections.push(contest);
      } else if (contest.type === 'Primary') {
        primaryElections.push(contest);
      }
    });

    console.log(primaryElections, generalElections, referendums);

    return (
      <div>
        <table className='table table-hover'>
          <caption>List of contests in your area</caption>
          {primaryElections.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <thead style={{ fontFamily: 'Righteous, sans-serif' }}>
                <tr>
                  <th scope='col' style={{ width: '10px' }}>
                    #
                  </th>
                  <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Office</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist Name</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist ID</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist Scope</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {primaryElections.map((election, idx) => (
                  <tr key={idx}>
                    <td style={{ width: '10px' }}>{idx + 1}</td>
                    <td>{election.type}</td>
                    <td>{election.office}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.name}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.scope}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.id}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </>
          )}
          {generalElections.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <thead style={{ fontFamily: 'Righteous, sans-serif' }}>
                <tr>
                  <th scope='col' style={{ width: '10px' }}>
                    #
                  </th>
                  <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Office</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist Name</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist ID</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Dist Scope</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {generalElections.map((election, idx) => (
                  <tr key={idx}>
                    <td style={{ width: '10px' }}>{idx + 1}</td>
                    <td>{election.type}</td>
                    <td>{election.office}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.name}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.scope}</td>
                    <td>{election.district.id}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </>
          )}
          {referendums.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <thead style={{ fontFamily: 'Righteous, sans-serif' }}>
                <tr>
                  <th scope='col' style={{ width: '10px' }}>
                    #
                  </th>
                  <th scope='col'>Type</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Title</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Subtitle</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Language</th>
                  <th scope='col'>District</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Scope</th>
                  <th scope='col'>Open Civic Data ID</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {referendums.map((referendum, idx) => (
                  <tr key={idx}>
                    <td style={{ width: '10px' }}>{idx + 1}</td>
                    <td>{referendum.type}</td>
                    <td>{referendum.referendumTitle}</td>
                    <td>{referendum.referendumSubtitle}</td>
                    <td>
                      <Link href={`${referendum.referendumUrl}`}>
                        <a>{referendum.referendumUrl}</a>
                      </Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{referendum.district.name}</td>
                    <td>{referendum.district.scope}</td>
                    <td>{referendum.district.id}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Contests;
```